# PHP - Combine and multiple values from two arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm pulling values from two different arrays to produce new arrays with only the values I want. Here are the two scripts. I'm basically finding the total revenue for all teams within a game.

**Script 1**

```
$allSales = array();
foreach ($game['sales'] as $sale) {
  foreach ($sale['values'] as $id => $values) {
    $allSales[$id]+=$values['y'];
  }
}  

print_r($allSales);
```

**Script 2**

```
$allPrices = array();
foreach ($game['products'] as $id => $product) {
  $allPrices[$id]+=$product['Price'];
}    

print_r($allPrices);
```

**The values I get look something like this:**

```
Array ( [0] => 500000000 [1] => 300000000 ) 
Array ( [0] => 300 [1] => 600 )
```

I want to be able to multiply the one array against the other in the same order of position. So `500000000 * 300` and `300000000 * 600` and produce a new array.

The reason I want a new array is because I will be sorting them from largest to smallest value and adding ranks to all of the values. I have another variable that has determined the current teams total sales revenue which I will compare to find their rank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe something along these lines:

`$result = array_map(function($a,$b){ return $a*$b; }, $array1, $array2);`

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php

Proof:

```
~$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $result = array_map(function($a,$b){ return $a*$b; }, array(1,2), array(3,4));
php > print_r($result);
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 8
)
php >
```

Comment: Oh I didn't see you basically did a copy paste of a basic MAP, I thought you had actually written in the array names so I just copied and pasted. Sorry bit on the tired side.

Comment: I personally find this version better, but it would be even better when combined in it's own function.

Comment: @Lumio; you mean like `$array_mul = function($a,$b)( return "what I wrote"; )` - why would that be better ?

Comment: No, I mean like function combineValues($a, $b) { return 'what you did with the right indentation etc'; } - and why? I personally find it more readable that having it as a oneliner

Comment: well yes, I agree if you use it more than once - but the only "better" thing you get out of it is that a `function a(..` is compile-time optimized by php. A far as "code style" goes I would not mix a 'pure' function `return map(fn,a,b)` with an outputting one `print`. reduces re-usability

Answer (score 1):

When both arrays have the same length then you could do

```
$comparison = array();
foreach ($allPrices as $index => $value) {
  $comparison[$index] = $value * $allSales[$index];
}

print_r($comparison);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$finalArray = array();
foreach ($allSales as $id => $eachSale) {
    $finalArray[$id]=$eachSale * $allPrices[$id];
} 
print_r($finalArray );
```

Comment: Tried this one and it only produced the sale price for each. Very close. @lumio's work though, should compare the difference.

Comment: @dvoutt: I couldnt understand what do u mean?

Comment: I think it might of been the space in the print out. Either way the two scripts are the same so it should work just didn't on first attempt.